# Calculate production end time across multiple shift start times

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

Using excel, I am trying to figure out how to calculate the end time in production when I have multiple shifts. The function writing isn't a problem (I don't think) and if I had just one shift, it would be a simple "cases remaining / (workers * production rate)" (ie. =a1/(b1*c1). My problem is, production increases as a second shift begins 4 hours after the first, then declines at the end of the first shift. I've thought of mapping out each hour and the production for each hour, but I don't know how I would add up all the production to give me an end time.

So my question is, what sort of calculation would I use that would account for changes in quantity of workers throughout the day and give me an end time? If I know the math involved, I shouldn't have a problem writing the functions.

Comment: We can't help you because the question doesn't include any description of what actually determines production end time and what data you have to work with. Please add some sample data and an example of your desired output.

Comment: Math involved - one day = 86400 seconds. In excel, time is calculated as a fraction of one full day (86400 seconds). So 10.30AM = ((10*60*60)+(30*60))/86400 = 37800/86400 whereas 6.20PM = ((18*60*60)+(20*60))/86400 = 66000/86400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Determine the end time of production]

At the heart of your problem is the simultaneous calculation of quantity and time. Therefore there are many approaches one might take to design a worksheet that presents both in a useful context. The one above came to my mind. You may be able to take some of my solution's components and embed them in a design of your own.

Top to bottom, my form has a cell for entering the production quantity. Obviously, this could be anywhere on a sheet, even in a table or other list or another sheet. My formulas refer to it as $B$2 because that's where it is in my test sheet.

Then there are start and end times of shifts. You could have as many shifts as you want but it's critical that the times entered are true *Times*, meaning numeric values, not text. If your shifts extend into the next day be sure that you use Date/Time values. Display them in any format you wish. You can display *Mar 24, 2020 16:10:23* as "16:10 PM" (with the date hidden entirely but available for calculations). All done by cell formatting.

In row 6 I entered the production quantity per shift. Modify as required. Obviously, you should have as many shift columns as you have time of different production capacity. "Shift" may not be correct expression. Please don't let it bother you.

In row 8 there are these formulas

```
[B8] =IF($B$2>=SUM($B6:B6),B6,MAX($B$2-IF(COLUMN()=COLUMN($B$6),0,SUM(A6:$B6)),0))
    copy this across B8:D8, and
[E8] =$B$2-SUM($B8:D8)
```

Similarly, in row 10 there are the formulas given below.

```
[B10] =IF(C8,"",IF(B8,B4+((B5-B4)/B6*B8),""))
    copy this across B10:D10, and
[E10] =IF(SUM(B10:D10),"","pending")
```

These formulas will leave row 10 blank except for the completion time which will appear in the column of the shift when completion occurs. Enter various target quantities in B2 when you test. Remember, for thorough testing, to enter quantities which are both less than the first shift's production quantity and more than an entire day's production, as well as exactly matching quantities.

I thought the shifting location of the result a little odd. Therefore I condensed it into a single field in B12, just to show how it can be done. There is an array formula there which you can see in the picture's Formula Bar. In case you aren't familiar with array formulas, the curly braces you see aren't part of them. Type the formula without them into the Formula Bar, then complete the entry with *Ctl+Shift+Enter* (in place of the customary singular *Enter*) and Excel will add the braces. Not entered correctly, the braces will not be shown and the formula will not work. Please note that the time format in this cell isn't produced by the formula but by the cell format.

Comment: I like it. I was thinking I would have to use some form of sin() or some other crazy math thing I never learned about in school. Your solution is one I hadn't considered. Thank you! I think I can adapt it to work for me.

Comment: So my solution involved changing start/end times as each hour and expanding it for the entire day. Then including worker count*cases per hour=production and including some if() functions to account for worker count changes throughout the day. Works perfectly! Thank you!